# count Total rows of an Id from another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I  have a dataframe

**Intialise data of lists.**

```
data = {'Id':['1', '2', '3', '4','5','6','7','8','9','10'], 'reply_id':[2, 2,2, 5,5,6,8,8,1,1]}
```

**Create DataFrame**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   Id   reply_id
0   1   2
1   2   2
2   3   2
3   4   5
4   5   5
5   6   6
6   7   8
7   8   8
8   9   1
9   10  1
```

I want to get total of `reply_id` in `new` for every `Id`.

Id=1 have 2 time occurrence in `reply_id` which i want in new column `new`

**Desired output**

```
    Id  reply_id  new
0   1   2          2   
1   2   2          3     
2   3   2          0 
3   4   5          0
4   5   5          2
5   6   6          1
6   7   8          0
7   8   8          2
8   9   1          0
9   10  1          0
```

I have done this line of code.

```
df['new'] = df.reply_id.eq(df.Id).astype(int).groupby(df.Id).transform('sum')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer, I used `Series.value_counts` to count values in reply_id, and converted the result to a dict. Then, I used `Series.map` on the `Id` column to associate counts to Id. `fillna(0)` is used to fill values not present in `reply_id`

```
df['new'] = (df['Id']
             .astype(int)
             .map(df['reply_id'].value_counts().to_dict())
             .fillna(0)
             .astype(int))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use, [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on the column `reply_id`, then use the aggregation function [`GroupBy.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) to create a mapping series `counts`, finally use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the values in `Id` column with their respective `counts`:

```
counts = df['reply_id'].groupby(df['reply_id']).count()
df['new'] = df['Id'].map(counts).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

   Id  reply_id  new
0   1         2    2
1   2         2    3
2   3         2    0
3   4         5    0
4   5         5    2
5   6         6    1
6   7         8    0
7   8         8    2
8   9         1    0
9  10         1    0
```

Comment: I tried your solution as it is quite similar to mine, but yours fills `new` with zeroes

Comment: What do you mean by `fill with zeros`?

Comment: I mean that all values in `new` are zeros

Comment: Well then, there is something weird happening on my side. I used the exact data provided in the question, and the exact lines you wrote, and can't get anything out of them :(

Comment: Yeah, i guess so..bcz, i have tested the above solution and produce the desired results.

Comment: Okay, I figured out what is the problem: the Id column contains strings in the question, if you don't use `astype(int)` before applying map, nothing will be mapped because your groupby will yield int, not strings

Comment: Actually i've copied the data from the given dataframe using `pd.read_clipboard`, i guess that's why it happened ;).